# Solve this up down riddle calmly

Tags: riddle

I go up,

I come down,

I don't go sideways,

I even oscillate,

don't let me leak,

because I have poison in me,

You pump me,

I get pressurised,

but I rise not go down,

Newer generation is better than me,

since they have no Hg.

Comment: Had to upvote this simply because the answer is now my new favorite word. Excellent puzzle, by the way!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is:

> A sphygmomanometer, the device used to measure blood pressure.

Explanation:

> With a manual sphygmomanometer the cuff placed around the arm is pumped up, applying pressure until it stops the blood flow in the artery under the cuff. The pressure is then slowly released  while the clinician listens with a stethoscope for the point at which the blood flow resumes, and then when it is no longer restricted (systolic and diastolic pressures). Mercury is used to measure the pressure in some manual sphygmomanometers but these are being replaced by safer technology. Newer, digital sphygmomanometers use oscillations in the cuff rather than mercury to measure blood pressure.

Comment: Could you please explain your answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The answer is

> Mercury Thermometer.....replaced by digital thermometers now.

Comment: Those can still be [analogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galinstan#Uses) without "hg", too.

Answer (score 2):

Could also be a

> Mercurial Barometer.  [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer#Mercury_barometers)  Nowadays, there are plenty of other options, from aneroids to digital.